# What manga chapter does the Hunter x Hunter 2011 anime end on?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

The *Hunter x Hunter* anime has concluded after 148 episodes.

[image: An ending shot from one of the final episodes (147)]

However, the manga continues on after this, focusing on new characters and events. If I want to pick up the manga from where the anime left off, what chapter or volume should I start at?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the Hunter x Hunter wiki, the corresponding manga chapter for episode 148 is chapter 338 and 339. Some specific plot points to consider:

- Gon's friends Killua and Alluka have already departed Gon from the previous episode, 147. This happens in chapter 338.
- Gon climbs up the World Tree and meets Ging. This happens in chapter 338.
- Ging explains where the Chimera Ants are from, that they're not from this world. This happens in chapter 338.
- In chapter 339, in the Zoldyck's estate, Canary and Amane makes a grave for Gotoh.
- At the very end of chapter 339, in East Gorteau, Komugi and Meruem are shown holding hands. This corresponds to the end of episode 148.

http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_338

http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_339

Answer (score 6):

My guess is 338 "Up in a tree" based on the previews for 148, although who knows they might include a little of 339 although I doubt it.

The reason I state this, is that in the preview of 148, and at the end of 147, the plot is left at the point where Gon is traveling to the World's Tree to meet Ging. This is exactly what happens in 338 of the manga, hence the name "Up in a Tree"