# Any more HxH stories or episodes out there?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I've watched all 148 episodes of the Hunter x Hunter anime, and even the movie "The Last Mission." Now I want to know if there is anything else to watch? Are there any more movies, or maybe some new episodes coming out?

Comment: You missed a movie [Hunter x Hunter Movie: Phantom Rouge](http://myanimelist.net/anime/13271/Hunter_x_Hunter_Movie__Phantom_Rouge). New manga is coming out every week. Read those that are released in 2016.

Comment: You can watch the 1999 series if you want the old-school feels ;). Some of the voice actors are different tho ><

Comment: If you want to know the progress of Hunter x Hunter I suggest you visit [here](https://hiatus-hiatus.rhcloud.com/). Just bookmark it and forget about it. Eventually, whenever you want to know if there's something new, just go back to it. New episodes *could* very well happen, but in order for that to happen, we need to see more chapters of the manga released. At the rate the author is going, it may take a few more years.

Answer (score 1):

The 2011 series covers roughly chapters 1 to 339 of the manga, as documented in [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/14410/27935) by Frosteeze.

Since then, **21 new chapters** have been released (as of september 2016, see [here](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_360) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hunter_%C3%97_Hunter_chapters#Chapters_not_yet_in_volume_format)).

*Update*: As The Pickle Tickler [mentions](https://anime.stackexchange.com/revisions/36191/2), "it has been announced that the manga is getting a continuation in 2016, as stated [here](http://www.jobsnhire.com/articles/38365/20160319/hunter-x-hunter-manga-continuation-2016.htm)."

In addition to "The Last Mission", another anime film was released in 2013, **"[Phantom Rouge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunter_%C3%97_Hunter:_Phantom_Rouge)"**.

[image]

Other than that, you have [the original 1999 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hunter_%C3%97_Hunter_(1999)_episodes), a [set of 30 OVA episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hunter_%C3%97_Hunter_OVA_episodes), and a 1998 short film, "Jump Super Anime Tour 98". None of them include material not covered by the 2011 series, as far as I know.

Comment: I think you should also mention that even though new chapters were released between April and June 2016, it has since gone back on Hiatus.